# browserify is installed, but is not available in command line

Tags: node.js, npm

I install Browserify:

> npm install -g browserify

then I try to run it:

> $ browserify main.js > bundle.js

and Windows says

> 'browserify' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Why is that? The [Browserify page](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) promises it will work, but it does not.

Comment: Make sure that where `browserify` is installed is accessible from your PATH environment variable.

Comment: And where is it? It shows me that it is installed at "c:\Users\shalmuy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\", but there is no executable file there!

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this issue by

```
npm uninstall browserify --save
npm install browserify -g
npm install browserify-shim -- save
```

Answer (score 7):

First, I installed browserify: `npm i -D browserify`

Then I ran `node .\node_modules\browserify\bin\cmd.js` instead of `browserify`.

For example, instead of:

```
browserify index.js -o bundle.js
```

I ran:

```
node .\node_modules\browserify\bin\cmd.js index.js -o bundle.js
```

Comment: This is a great option for GraalVM

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```js
npx browserify index.js -o bundle.js
```

**NPX** is a little-known command that is used to run binaries from modules that are installed locally in node_modules.

Answer (score 2):

*As of **December 12th 2021***

Use this command in `cmd` to convert your file :

`npx browserify index.js -o bundle.js`

at `index.js`, place your file name instead of this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem. I had a corrupted installation of npm package, which did not create "browserify.cmd" file for some reason. I reinstalled it and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and resolved it by editing my Environmental Variables.

In other words I added the path to where my npm folder holding browserify was to list of Environmental Variables, PATH.

Hope this helps:)